# Merge/Load same files in multiple folders in S3 into Snowflake

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task, snowflake-pipe

Need help on how to achieve in loading the same file available in multiple folders into the snowflake table. Is it possible to achieve using `Snowflake Copy Command`?

Say in a bucket I have .. All the files of a.csv  which are only under the current date example here 2020/06/09  will go into `a_table`

2020 -- is the year followed by month 06 followed by date which is 09

```
bucket_a
   ts
     ts_folder
         2020
           06
             08
                a.csv
                b.csv
                c.csv
                d.csv
             09
                a.csv
                b.csv
                c.csv
                d.csv

     ts_folder2
         2020
           06
             08
                a.csv
                b.csv
                c.csv
                d.csv
             09
                a.csv
                b.csv
                c.csv
                d.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Snowflake COPY INTO statement is will recursively crawl through the subdirectories in the stage, so all you need to do is add a pattern parameter to your COPY INTO statement, something like this:

```
pattern = 'a\_date\.csv'
```

Comment: thanks for the update, I have updated the original question. I want all same files falling under same date only those files need to be loaded. Below command gets data from  all the dates files which I don't want
`select $1,$2 from @stage/ts/ (file_format=>CSV_SKIP_HEADER,pattern=>'.*/file.*[.]csv');
`

Answer (score 1):

Achieved using below code

```
SET curr_dt=(
  SELECT 
    '.*/' || 
    TO_VARCHAR(CURRENT_DATE(), 'YYYY/MM/DD') || 
    '/a\\.csv'
)

-- Referenced as a SQL variable in the PATTERN option
COPY INTO a_table
FROM @stage/ts/
(PATTERN=>$curr_dt);
```